# How should I configure my Apache Hosts File to serve a different site for localhost than for my domain/publicip?

Tags: django, apache-2.2, web

I'm trying to test out a LAMP (with PHP5 specifically) setup with Django already serving a website. I want to do the PHP stuff on `localhost` for now, so that when I do something like this: `curl http://localhost/database/script.php?var=1`, I get a response from the php server. Right now I'm getting a Django error. I tried something like this in the `default` file in `sites-available`:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /home/phpsite
</VirtualHost>
```

where `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` is the local ip address, and changing my actual site's settings to specify the public ip, like this:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost www.xxx.yyy.zzz>
ServerName mysite.com
DocumentRoot /srv/www/mysite
WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/mysite.wsgi    
</VirtualHost>
```

but then I start getting all kinds of errors when I start apache, such as `port ::[80] is already in use` or something. I noticed that the `hosts` file that's located in `/etc/apache2/` is apparently pointing everything to `mysite.com`, including my local ip as well as 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.1.1; Do I need to change the configuration there too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `NameVirtualHost`:

```
 NameVirtualHost *:80

 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.example.com
 ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
 DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot /srv/www/localhost
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: ok sorry, that was a stupid question. I think I tried that but thought it wasn't working because I did `curl http://localhost` and got a 404, not bothering to pay attention to the fact that it was from apache, not Django. Thank you.